# What is the song playing in the prologue of episode 150 of One Piece?

Tags: one-piece, music

In episode 150 of *One Piece*, there's a song playing on the prologue scene. This song was even in some prologues of Alabasta saga.

I've already listened to all soundtracks, but I couldn't find this song.

What is that song?

Comment: Just to be sure, you mean the opening or the really first music when they are explaining what happened in the last episode?

Answer (score 2):

The song that was played as intro in the episode 150 of One Piece was titled **Hikari e**.

> Kanji: ヒカリへ
>   Romaji: Hikari e
>   Meaning: Towards the Light
>   English: Towards the Light
>   Artist(s): The Babystars Album/Single: Hikari e
>   Label: Ki/oon Records
>   Track Length: 3:44
>   Intro length: 1:49
>   Anime Use: 3rd Opening: Episodes 116 - 168 (53 episodes)

More details about the song can be found on [Wikia](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Hikari_e).

Answer (score 1):

It was [Hikari e](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Hikari_e)

This was the opening song between episodes 115 and 168